# type narrowing return type of function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=61#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbygDwFxRICuAtgEYQBOA3FCAceVVAL5QA%20UA2oxZQDSFSfALrUAUOIDGcJAGdUAQ3RQAFPiFMBdBsKoBKAvGSo0APizioUShGBFKSLLkEhW4lpJnzUZFYtUARkEAJn0JaVk5OAAbCAA6GLgAc1UyeJxw6wB6bKhFJBArXJhKOEhKUCgAchxqqAATOAg5QjhUCBwEBShZKFBIGuMUavjivNgyiqra%20qaWto6unr6B6GqePW1eKhFRoA) and here is the code

```
type Point = { x: number; y: number } | [number, number];

const a = (x: number, y: number): Point => {
  return { x, y }
}

const b = a(1, 2);

console.log(b.x);  // any
 //Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Point'.
 //  Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.
```

Is there any way that I can avoid a guard function to type narrow on the return type so it just knows that it is an object and not a tuple of [number, number]?

The type is outside my control in [transformation matrix](https://github.com/chrvadala/transformation-matrix/blob/bdabb7a5b0c4b940704e797183c41eaf751a80fb/transformation-matrix.d.ts#L20)

Comment: Yes; declare the more specific return type `{x: number, y: number}`, or don't declare a return type and allow it to be inferred. The general rule is, when you declare a type annotation, then that overrides what Typescript would infer (though Typescript will check that the annotation is satisfied).

Comment: this type comes from an external library.  it seems like an awful type, am i wrong.

Comment: It seems pretty weird indeed. I don't see a reason not to normalize data/type here.

Comment: If you have no control over the type, I'd write a normalizing function like `const p = (v: Point)=>Array.isArray(v) ? { x: v[0], y: v[1] } : v;` and any `Point` objects I consume would be passed to `p()`, and any `Point` objects I produce would be declared as `{x: number; y: number}` and not `Point`.  Does that answer your question or do you need something else?

Comment: You should just let type inference do its thing. Don't type it at all. Is this is an overly simplified version of the actual code?